# Socket.io: 2 RN clients can only chat one way

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The RN (0.59) chat app uses socket.io (2.2.0) to communicate with Nodejs (10.16)/express (4.16) backend. There are 2 Android emulators connecting to the backend at the same time for testing, one on port 8081 and another on port 9090. Here is the code on backend server to handle socket:

```
    const io = req.app.get("io");
    const socket = req.app.get('socket');
    const room = msg.event_id.toString();  //<<<=== '1'
    socket.join(room);
    io.to(room).emit("event message", msg);
```

Here `io.to(room)` is used to send the new message to other socket clients connected. The message sent by client on port 9090 can be received on client on port 8081. However the message sent by client on port 8081 can not be received by client on port 9090. Also the message was sent to client on port 8081 twice. See image below. Left is the client on port 9090 and right is on port 8081:

[image]

Here is the output of socket from client on port 8081:

```
socket in new message :  Socket {
  nsp:
   Namespace {
     name: '/',
     server:
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        parentNsps: Map {},
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        parser: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {},
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Circular],
        eio: [Server],
        httpServer: [Server],
        engine: [Server] },
     sockets:
      { Akf0q7wpwolQNxNnAAAC: [Socket],
        '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': [Circular] },
     connected:
      { Akf0q7wpwolQNxNnAAAC: [Socket],
        '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': [Circular] },
     fns: [],
     ids: 0,
     rooms: [],
     flags: {},
     adapter:
      Adapter {
        nsp: [Circular],
        rooms: [Object],
        sids: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {} },
     _events: [Object: null prototype] { connection: [AsyncFunction] },
     _eventsCount: 1 },
  server:
   Server {
     nsps: { '/': [Namespace] },
     parentNsps: Map {},
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     parser:
      { protocol: 4,
        types: [Array],
        CONNECT: 0,
        DISCONNECT: 1,
        EVENT: 2,
        ACK: 3,
        ERROR: 4,
        BINARY_EVENT: 5,
        BINARY_ACK: 6,
        Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
        Decoder: [Function: Decoder] },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets:
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Circular],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        rooms: [],
        flags: {},
        adapter: [Adapter],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     eio:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 2,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [WebSocketServer],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     httpServer:
      Server {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 3,
        _handle: [TCP],
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9 },
     engine:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 2,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [WebSocketServer],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 } },
  adapter:
   Adapter {
     nsp:
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Server],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        rooms: [],
        flags: {},
        adapter: [Circular],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     rooms:
      { '1': [Room],
        Akf0q7wpwolQNxNnAAAC: [Room],
        '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': [Room] },
     sids:
      { Akf0q7wpwolQNxNnAAAC: [Object],
        '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': [Object] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  id: '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD',
  client:
   Client {
     server:
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        parentNsps: Map {},
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        parser: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {},
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Namespace],
        eio: [Server],
        httpServer: [Server],
        engine: [Server] },
     conn:
      Socket {
        id: '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD',
        server: [Server],
        upgrading: false,
        upgraded: false,
        readyState: 'open',
        writeBuffer: [],
        packetsFn: [],
        sentCallbackFn: [],
        cleanupFn: [Array],
        request: [IncomingMessage],
        remoteAddress: '::ffff:192.168.2.133',
        checkIntervalTimer: null,
        upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: 30000,
           _idlePrev: [TimersList],
           _idleNext: [Timeout],
           _idleStart: 3599298,
           _onTimeout: [Function],
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2218,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 399 },
        transport: [WebSocket],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3 },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { reconstructor: null, _callbacks: [Object] },
     id: '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD',
     request:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: true,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Socket],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        parser: null,
        _query: [Object],
        websocket: [WebSocket] },
     onclose: [Function: bound ],
     ondata: [Function: bound ],
     onerror: [Function: bound ],
     ondecoded: [Function: bound ],
     sockets: { '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': [Circular] },
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     connectBuffer: [] },
  conn:
   Socket {
     id: '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD',
     server:
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 2,
        wsEngine: 'ws',
        pingTimeout: 5000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Array],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: '/',
        cookieHttpOnly: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        initialPacket: [Array],
        ws: [WebSocketServer],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     upgrading: false,
     upgraded: false,
     readyState: 'open',
     writeBuffer: [],
     packetsFn: [],
     sentCallbackFn: [],
     cleanupFn: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     request:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        aborted: false,
        upgrade: true,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Socket],
        _consuming: false,
        _dumped: false,
        parser: null,
        _query: [Object],
        websocket: [WebSocket] },
     remoteAddress: '::ffff:192.168.2.133',
     checkIntervalTimer: null,
     upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
     pingTimeoutTimer:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 3599298,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 2218,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 399 },
     transport:
      WebSocket {
        readyState: 'open',
        discarded: false,
        socket: [WebSocket],
        writable: true,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        supportsBinary: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        sid: '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD',
        req: [IncomingMessage] },
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        close: [Array],
        data: [Function: bound ],
        error: [Function: bound ] },
     _eventsCount: 3 },
  rooms: { '1': '1', '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD': '-rD5m1TUdZ0D6_8pAAAD' },
  acks: {},
  connected: true,
  disconnected: false,
  handshake:
   { headers:
      { origin: 'http://192.168.2.133:3000',
        upgrade: 'websocket',
        connection: 'Upgrade',
        'sec-websocket-key': '28/WtfDvCyPzZjpT52PzPA==',
        'sec-websocket-version': '13',
        host: '192.168.2.133:3000',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
        'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.12.1' },
     time: 'Wed Jun 12 2019 22:24:03 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)',
     address: '::ffff:192.168.2.133',
     xdomain: true,
     secure: false,
     issued: 1560403443089,
     url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
     query: { EIO: '3', transport: 'websocket' } },
  fns: [],
  flags: {},
  _rooms: [],
  my_id: 22,
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] { 'event message': [Function], disconnect: [AsyncFunction] },
  _eventsCount: 2 }
```

The primary problem is that the message from client on port 8081 can not be received on client on port 9090. The minor issue is that the message from client on port 8081 is sent to itself again (duplicate message).

Comment: Both clients are having the same socket.id on server output when saving new message. But the clients have different socket.id on app end output.